# MySQL computed column

Tags: mysql

Helllo, I have the following table structure

Scores table:

```
|..ID..User_ID..Test_ID....Test_Score |
|.5.......1.........1...............999.....|
|.4.......1.........3...............120.....|
|.3.......1.........2...............115.....|
|.2.......2.........2...............200.....|
|.1.......2.........3...............123.....|
```

Users table:

```
|..ID...Username...TotalTestScore......|
|.2.......Nick................1400...........|
|.1.......Mike................1222...........|
```

My goal is to make TotalTestScore column to save the sum of all the scores associated with this User_ID from Scores table on change to the Scores table.
I'm thinking about doing it with trigger, but don't really know how to start. Can someone say if what I'm doing is even possible and possibly give a hint.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hint: use a `JOIN` and an aggregate function such as `SUM()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have *millions of gazillions* of users and test scores, and **NO INDEXES** I would not recomend storing the total test scores as this could simply be returned using a query, *no triggers, no stored columns, no problem*...

```
SELECT  u.ID, 
        u.UserName, 
        SUM(s.Test_Score) TotalTestScore
FROM    Users u LEFT JOIN
        Scores s ON u.ID = s.User_ID
GROUP BY    u.ID, 
            u.UserName
```

Comment: A view would probably be safe.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO A view would be safe yes, but to create a view for every single query the OP needs might be over kill. If such a view is used more than once/regularly and the view contains some complex business logic, I would say create such a view.

Comment: This looks like something I can use. Thanks!